# CSS infinite animation after hidden is not reset (Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

Here I have an example of CSS keyframe animation (You can see the whole thing  on [**this Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/umbreak/q234Lsx8/1/))

The code will every 1.4 seconds scale the img to 0.75 and go back to it's original (1) scale. That works fine.

Then I add a simple jQuery code to simulate the error:

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    $("img").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    activate();
}, 3000);

function activate() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("img").css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, 3000);
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes imagebulger {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(.75);
        transform: scale(.75);
    }
}
@keyframes imagebulger {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(.75);
        transform: scale(.75);
    }
}
img {
    -webkit-animation: imagebulger 1.4s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: imagebulger 1.4s infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: imagebulger 1.4s infinite alternate;
    animation: imagebulger 1.4s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
```

This will hide the img element after 3 seconds and during 3 seconds. **When the img element is back to to visible, the resizing effect will not be running anymore.**

It happens to me in Chrome 41.0.2272 (Ubuntu). In Firefox it works as expected.

---

**EDIT**

Looks like is bug in with Chrome. I opened an issue. As a workaround, like suggested, either use `display:none` instead of `vissibility:hidden` or add a class after setting `vissibility:visible`

**EDIT 2**
There is an issue opened here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444852

Comment: I am on Chrome 24 (yea, very old I know) and the animation does work properly even after hide and re-appear.

Comment: First time I run it it does not even hide for me too, after I run it again it does.
However, the issue is with the animation after visibility is set to visible again.

Comment: Yea, I noted that mate. Sorry for that comment and that's why I removed it immediately. However, the animation does seem to work for me even after re-appearing.

Comment: Dont know what causes the issue but using `opacity` it works http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/q234Lsx8/4/

Comment: Thanks! However, opactiy 0 is not totally the same as visibility hidden. 

And, the most important, the jquery (plugin) I am using sets the "not visible" fields to `visibility: hidden`

Comment: @DidacMontero: I can confirm that I see the issue in GC38+. So it seems like something that was working in GC24/25 must have got removed knowingly/unknowingly. Maybe you could add that in your Chrome issue thread.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug.  The [W3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-visibility) suggests that visibility hidden have the following effect:

> The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout. Furthermore, descendants of the element will be visible if they have 'visibility: visible'.

Hence it should still be being calculated, just not drawn.  Obviously the browser will probably want to make savings and *not* calculate it where possible, which seems to be where the bug is arising when this calculation doesn't recommence when it should.  You can get around it by toggling the `display` and wrapping your animating element in a div of the same size as the element in order to prevent the layout collapsing.  Otherwise you could just reapply the animation CSS by toggling the class as Jeff states.

Please see the JS fiddle showing a hidden element still clearly being animated: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5q3r4hk/).  This leads me to think it's a bug.  Otherwise the below is an example of it working toggling `display`.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    $("img").hide();
    activate();
}, 3000);

function activate() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("img").show();
    }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.image-wrap {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imagebulger {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(.75);
        transform: scale(.75);
    }
}
@keyframes imagebulger {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(.75);
        transform: scale(.75);
    }
}
img {
    -webkit-animation: imagebulger 1.4s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: imagebulger 1.4s infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: imagebulger 1.4s infinite alternate;
    animation: imagebulger 1.4s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-wrap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah! I've also noticed that the highlighted area was still animated, even when it was not rendered the animation. I will open a report.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a work around and a bug report ;)

Comment: I will accept this as informative and as a workaround (in the cases when you can change `visibility:hidden` for `display:none`. 

However, in some cases (external jQuery pugins) you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into issues with animations stopping their execution before.  The solution for me has always been to reapply the animation as a class whenever I want it to restart.  I modified your fiddle with this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/q234Lsx8/5/

I made the CSS rule apply to `img.bulge`, and then the jQuery code removes and adds the class `bulge` on hide and show.

Comment: Yeah I've seen this workaround [here](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/).

So I assume is an Issue related with Chrome and it has to be reported.