# CSS animations stop after hidden then shown in Chrome

Tags: css

I've got a modal overlay where the css spinner rotates when first loaded, after hiding then showing again the spinner no longer rotates.

This only happens in Chrome and only happens when the spinner is not visible from the outset (ie if the div is hidden then toggled - the animation happens as expected). Is this a bug or have I missed something?

**EDIT** It seems to be the visibility that it doesn't like, commenting this out, everything performs as expected

It also seems to be a bug, behaves as expected in Canary 46

**EDIT** I've though this was a duplicate: [CSS infinite animation after hidden is not resetted (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167467/css-infinite-animation-after-hidden-is-not-resetted-chrome), however that works in the same version of Chrome

```js
document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('loader').classList.toggle('out');
}
```

```css
#holder {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background: #cc0000
}
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s linear;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
.loader.out {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <button id="toggle">Toggle Overlay</button>
</div>

<div id="holder">
  <div class="loader" id="loader">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working fine for me in Chrome 45

Comment: Hmm, works for me in 46 Canary, but it says my 44 is up to date - feels like a bug